# Strange bug with css3 gradient stripes

Tags: css, gradient

I`m trying to create 135 degrees classic candy stripe using pure css3. 
After some reading, and trying I finally am pretty close to success, but there is an annoying problem that keep bugging me.

Here is my example [with code](http://dabblet.com/gist/6902135):  and [without](http://result.dabblet.com/gist/6902135/7b6b72a5d0306ee1c2bce73db39ec1a111e3f5f8) 
As you can probably see now, there is some weird stuff at the left side of the pattern.
So the question is - what is this and how can I make it go away?
P.S. chrome users may see that stripes are pretty messy - additional thanks if somebody can find how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with one single `repeating-linear-gradient`.

```
repeating-linear-gradient(135deg, #ff6d81, #ff6d81 8px, #fff 9px, #fff 16px, #00B2CB 17px, #00B2CB 24px, #fff 25px, #fff 32px);
```

[Here it is in action](http://dabblet.com/gist/6902526).

The first property is the angle of the gradients, then you can add as many gradients as needed, usually pairs of 'start' and 'stop' points.

More information [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/repeating-linear-gradient).

The MDN is a really good javascript and CSS resource if you haven't got it bookmarked.

Comment: Wow, that`s great! Thank you, good sir. In fact I checked MDN  several times, but as we can see could get it right by myself. Ok, now I have to deal only with chrome bug, yey!